# How do the Sort tabs work on Stack Overflow and why the querystring?

Tags: discussion

What happens under the hood when we click one of the tabs? (Newest, Featured, Faq, etc).

There's a querystring `sort` on the URL which identifies the type of sort, or in some cases the type of filter (at least in the case of Unanswered and Active).

Does each sort type use a separate `ActionResult` or is there one `ActionResult` for sorted results and one for filtered results?

My guess is that a querystring was used instead of a separate routing URL because some actions use one `ActionResult` and others user another. (or something similar).

Is this how it works or is there something much more in-depth going on?

Answer (score 2):

The URL corresponds to a single `ActionResult` method.  The query string is most likely passed to a method on a repository object (utilizing a micro ORM called [Dapper](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) to get the results from the SQL Server database), and a collection of results is returned, sorted in the chosen order.  Said collection is then passed to the View for rendering.